# C program performance depreciation after multiple runs

Tags: python, c, performance, testing, memory-leaks

To properly test a piece of software (written in C) I have been working on, I have to run a high volume of tests. I've been doing this with a python script that executes my software a given number of times (generally in the range of 1000 - 10000 repititions), one after the other. I am working on a debian virtual machine (500mb ram). I've been noticing that over time the performance of the program depreciates significantly. Usually I have to go so far as rebooting the vm to get back to normal performance levels.

My first thought was a memory leak, but valgrind did not discover any in my C program. Furthermore, I would have thought the OS would take care of that after program termination either way. When I run top or free -m, I see that free ram is fairly low (20-70mb), but does not drop much while running my script, instead fluctuating around where it started.

Edit: A full rundown on what my files are doing is as follows:

C software

- Many files, developed by various people
- Features a loop that continues until given destination IP has been discovered
- Constructs packets based off of given destination and information received from previously sent packets
- Sends packets
- Waits for packet replies

Python script emulating network topology

- Stores fake networks
- Intercepts outgoing packets and sends replies based off of said topology

Python testing script

- For a given number of repetitions,
- Launch network emulator
- Launch C software (wait until terminated - the process launches are actually done with a bash script)
- Exit network emulator

Output for the emulator and the c software are both dumped to log files, which are overwritten at each execution (so they should be kept decently short).

Can anyone give me some pointers as to what this could be?

Comment: You might have a resource leak. Do you free all memory you allocate? Close all files or network connections you open?

Comment: What sort of things is the C code doing? Are there any external resources involved? I agree with @JoachimPileborg that it seems likely that it could be a resource leak. It's also possible that even without a leak you may have a limited resource that is slow recovering after it's freed.

Comment: Free memory is supposed to be low.  It's used as disk cache.  Check system-wide limits like no. of processes and open files.

Comment: @TRKemp I like the idea that this could be something slow to recover. What kind of scenarios cause this and how should I go about properly confirming that such is the case?

Comment: It really depends on what resources you are using. Some network connections take a while to timeout even if they are closed correctly. There are other resources that can have extended recovery times too. For example, a file system may need to flush caches, which can take a while.

Another thing to consider, if you are pounding a limited resource with allocations and deallocations and it's heavily stressed, some resources will temporarily change timers to prevent the system from being overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

this could be:

- some leak in the python script
- waiting on a resource in the c script/python script
- writing to a file that gets bigger during the run
- C software doesn't close properly

and so on. You could elaborate on what the C software does to get us more clues, also state whether other software also runs more slowly.